# Como colocar em ordem crescente as variáveis do eixo Y no ggplot

Tags: r

Eu tive de renomear as variáveis Y de um ggplot, mas preciso que elas fiquem em ordem crescente de forma que os dados acompanhem corretamente suas variáveis. Preciso que comece pelo #MB02

```
myc_t
DateTime    Receiver    Transmitter ID  Transmitter.Serial  Sensor.Value Sensor.Unit    Station Name    Longitude   Latitude
2019-04-29  05:31:33    134321  4828    Fran    1305297         28.7       °C             PRN               102          121
2019-04-29  08:52:08    134325  4830    Beni    1305283         4.2         m             MVW               102          178
2019-04-29  08:53:13    134325  4831    Silvo   1305283         28.6       °C             MVW               150          178


ggplot(myc_t,aes(x=DateTime,y=Transmitter)) +  geom_point(stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "Período de monitoramento acústico", y = "Frequência de detecção")+ scale_y_discrete(labels = c("#MB04", "#MB05","#MB06","#MB07","#MB08","#MB03","#MB09","#MB10", "#MB11", "#MB12", "#MB02", "#MB13", "#MB14", "#MB15", "#MB16"))
```

Comment: Oi franciele, vc pode pf passar seus dados com dput() do jeito que esta eh dificil de responder, mas provavelente vc vai usar algo com `aes(x = DateTime,y = fct_reorder(Transmitter,alguma_coluna)`

Comment: Veja o guia de como fazer uma boa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r)

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do data.frame, antes de transformar ele em um objeto ggplot, classifique essa variável usando a função sort, que colocará em ordem alfabética.

Exemplo:

```
dados = dados[sort(dados$variavel),]
```

Se essa variável ainda não estiver no seu data.frame, você pode adicioná-la com base em alguma coluna.

Exemplo:
Quero criar uma coluna com base em outra coluna com uma nova categoria. Digamos que eu quero colocar na nova coluna "GEOCOD", o número "53" para as linhas cujo estado é "DF".

```
dados$GEOCOD[dados$UF == "DF"]= "53"
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, primeiramente, use a função "reorder" dentro do parâmetro y. Vou aproveitar também para sugerir uma forma melhor de organização do seu código, para facilitar até mesmo sua compreensão e de outrem que precisem trabalhar contigo, ok? Assim:

```
ggplot(data = myc_t,
       aes(x = DateTime,
           y = reorder(Transmitter, -DateTime))) +
       geom_point(stat = "identity") +
       labs(x = "Período de monitoramento acústico",
            y = "Frequência de detecção")+ 
       scale_y_discrete(labels = c("#MB04", "#MB05","#MB06","#MB07","#MB08","#MB03","#MB09","#MB10", "#MB11", "#MB12", "#MB02", "#MB13", "#MB14", "#MB15", "#MB16"))
```

A função "reorder" vai organizar os valores de "y" em ordem crescente, caso queira em ordem decrescente, utilize o "+" ao invés do "-". Se quiser que o "x" seja organizado dessa forma, ao invés do "y", basta tirar a função reorder de "y" e colocar em "x".